# Efficiently reconcile changing identifiers in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am working with data where the user identifier changes. The user identifiers are GUIDs, so shouldn't repeat across different users. When the identifier changes, I am provided with the old user identifier and the current user identifier on the same row in a table. I need to reconcile these values and have them both assigned to the same database-generated integer ID, which is the value I use to refer to the user elsewhere in the database.

Not long ago, the user identifiers would not change. I had the following setup:

```
users table
id | identifier
---------------
1  | ABC
2  | DEF
etc ...

activity table
id | timestamp | identifier      | other_data
---------------------------------------------
...
29 | 1         | ABC             | more data
30 | 2         | ABC             | even more data
31 | 3         | ABC             | etc
32 | 4         | DEF             | etc
33 | 5         | DEF             | etc
34 | 6         | ABC             | more data
...
```

My goal remains to aggregate activity from the `activity` table into an `activity_daily` table. In the prior setup, that was relatively simple because I could expect that the `identifier` was consistent per user.

My output aggregate `activity_daily` table had the structure:

```
id | user_id | date      | other_stuff
--------------------------------------
1  | 1       | 9/10/2017 | etc
2  | 1       | 9/11/2017 | etc
3  | 2       | 9/08/2017 | etc
4  | 2       | 9/09/2017 | etc
5  | 1       | 9/12/2017 | etc
...
```

Now, however, the `activity` table has changed. For the first activity record where a `identifier` changes, I get a value in a column called `identifier_old`. The activity table now looks like the following:

```
activity table
id | timestamp | identifier      | identifier_old      | other_data
-------------------------------------------------------------------
...
29 | 110       | ABC             |                     | more data
30 | 111       | GHI             | ABC                 | other data
31 | 112       | GHI             |                     | etc
32 | 114       | DEF             |                     | etc
33 | 115       | DEF             |                     | etc
34 | 116       | JKL             | DEF                 | etc
35 | 117       | GHI             |                     | etc
36 | 118       | JKL             |                     | etc
37 | 119       | JKL             |                     | etc
38 | 120       | GHI             |                     | etc
...
```

Now, my need to to create the same aggregate `activity_daily` table with the added complexity of mapping the `identifier` and `identifier_old` to the same integer `id` in the `users` table.

Each day, somewhere around 10 million records are loaded into the `activity` table that have to be reconciled and aggregated. There are millions of unique `identifiers`, so I'm trying to keep the reconciling of the identifiers and the aggregation steps as efficient as possible.

---

I've had two thoughts about how to approach this, but neither seem particularly efficient when considering the aggregation and joins on the `activity` table.

1) Create an `identifiers` table with columns `id`, `identifier`, and `user_id`. The `users` table no longer stores the `identifier`. Then do the following: a) check if the `identifier_old` is in the `identifiers` table. If not, add it and create an entry in the `users` table to generate an id. Add that id to the proper record in the `identifiers` table. b) Look in the `activity` table at records that have a value both in `identifier` and `old_identifier`. Add the `identifier` from those records to the `identifiers` table and then update those records with the appropriate `user_id` values from the `old_identifier` values that are already in the `identifier` table. c) Do my aggregation, etc. based on the `identifier` column in the `activity` table.

2) Similar, but don't maintain a separate `identifiers` table. Instead, add a third column to the `users` table called `user_static_id` (or something). All `identifier` values go into the `users` table but those that refer to the same person share the same `user_static_id` and the aggregate table has a foreign key for `user_static_id` instead of for the `id` column in the `users` table.

Neither of these seem like a great approach and both seem like they could significantly slow down the reconciliation and aggregation process.

Note: I cannot say, for certain, that the changed `identifier` values won't revert back to their previous values. For each user, they may continue to change periodically, they may revert, or they may remain static forever. The `timestamp` column in the `activity` table allows me to sort the records so that I don't end up encountering records with a new `identifier` before I encounter records that have both `identifier` and `identifier_old`.

It's also worth noting that the `activity` table is flushed after the aggregation has occurred.

Given this scenario, what is the most efficient way to handle this problem?

Comment: The  `identifier_old` column is redundant, IMHO. And: shouldn't 'GHI'-->>'DEF' also flag a change?

Comment: @wildplasser In the example, `ABC` migrates ID to `GHI` and `DEF` migrates to `JKL`. The `identifier_old` column is only populated in the incoming data when an ID migration occurred, so it's the only mapping of the migration that I have.

Comment: So you want in fact to relate your logs to a *canonical* identity? (independent of the changes in the identifiers)

Comment: @wildplasser That is correct.

Comment: Why don't you just log the numerical `users.id` column (which is stable)?

Comment: @wildplasser The logs come in from other sources that do not have access to the `users.id` column. They come in as identifiers in GUID form like `9fe94475-3bd3-4710-8878-9ed005b19257` that are expensive to index and perform joins on. Hence, my goal is to create the canonical `users.id` from them, which was far simpler before they started changing in the logs.

Comment: I would start by generating a side table to look up {identifier, interval} -->>canonical_user_id. You could also replace the *fat* GUIDs by an enumeration of them. (BTW: this starts to look like a data-vault kind of problem)